# AMPSCRIPT Triggering Send API in a Landing Page?

Tags: trigger, api, marketing-cloud, ampscript

Without using a posting form by a user, is there a way to automate a landing page to self execute on a daily basis using AMPSCRIPT and landing pages?

I can actually use Automation studio to do this, but I wanna be able to do it using AMPSCRIPT's Trigger Send API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to set up a send that uses `HTTPGet()` to call the page, in turn running the logic on the page.

It's not recommended.